# How to include a launch file from another node into a current project

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am launching a specific node called `roslaunch lidar_deck lidar_deck_rosbag.launch`

I created another node called tugInterface, and that also has a `launch` file called `roslaunch tugInterface tuginterface.launch`. I circled it in red below.

**The problem:**

I am trying to include the `launch` file called `roslaunch tugInterface tuginterface.launch` into the `roslaunch lidar_deck lidar_deck_rosbag.launch` but with no success.

Below the **lidar_deck lidar_deck_rosbag.launch**:

[image: node]

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<launch>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="segment_frame" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_footprint segment_frame 10"/>

  <node pkg="lidar_boat_detection" type="process_lidar" name="process_lidar" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="velodyne_bag_tranform" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_footprint velodyne 10"/>
  <!-- RViz -->
  <arg name="rviz" default="true"/>
  <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="$(anon rviz)" respawn="false" args="-d $(find lidar_deck)/rviz/lidar_deck_rosbag.rviz" />

</launch>
```

I tried also the following version but that also did not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<launch>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="segment_frame" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_footprint segment_frame 10"/>

  <node pkg="lidar_boat_detection" type="process_lidar" name="process_lidar" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="velodyne_bag_tranform" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 base_footprint velodyne 10"/>

<include file="$(find tugInterface)/launch/tuginterface.launch" />
<node pkg="tugInterface" type="tuginterface" name ="tuginterface" />

  <!-- RViz -->
  <arg name="rviz" default="true"/>
  <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="$(anon rviz)" respawn="false" args="-d $(find lidar_deck)/rviz/lidar_deck_rosbag.rviz" />

</launch>
```

In addition to that I also tried to add `<rosparam command="load" file="$(find tugInterface)/tuginterface.launch" />` to the `launch` file but still didn't work.
How can I solve that? Thanks for pointing to the right direction.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354163/how-to-include-a-launch-file-from-another-node-into-a-current-project/) by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2020-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) on 2020-06-05**:
Have you sourced both workspaces? I think otherwise it will not find the other node.
Oh sorry, your headline is a little bit confusing, because they are all in the same workspace/project.

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2020-06-05**:
Hello and thanks for reading the question. Yes the workspace is outsourced. I did it in the `.basrh` file so that I didn't have to worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your include command looks fine, here is an example of a launch file that works for me:
node_master.launch:

```
<launch>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find node_master)/config/node_master.yaml" />
    <include file="$(find node_1)/launch/full.launch"/>
    <include file="$(find node_2)/launch/full.launch"/>
    <include file="$(find node_3)/launch/full.launch"/>
</launch>
```

node_1/launch/full.launch:

```
   <launch>
        <node name="node_1_node" pkg="node_1" type="node_1_node" output="screen"/>
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find node_1)/config/param.yaml" />
    </launch>
```

But I think you are using this wrong:
After including the launch file of *tugInterface*  you are starting the node inside the same launchfile.

 That node should be instead started in the lauchfile you include, otherwise it's not needed to include that launchfile at all.

You should be able to start that node without including it's launchfile.

---

Originally posted by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) with karma: 272 on 2020-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on 2020-06-05**:
I see the mistake I am making. Thank you very much your clarification just helped me solve the problem! :)

**Comment by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) on 2020-06-05**:
You are welcome!